# The ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match. IIS has a value of WhenSupported while the WCF Transport has a value of Never

Tags: wcf, security, rest, iis-7.5, windows-authentication

I'm working on secured web site that handling WCF REST services.
Everything work fine untill I started to secured my site. 
I changed the authentication mode form anonymous to windows authentication and implemeted the autorization inside global.asax file.

For the website who design by MVC architecture and using internal services everything working as expected but the REST API is not working well.

I've addd the security configuration to web.config binding section as following:

```
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWindows">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

and:

```
   <binding name="webHttpBindingWindows">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
```

and with and without:

```
<extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="WhenSupported"></extendedProtectionPolicy>
```

but I got this exception:

> The extended protection settings configured on IIS do not match the settings configured on the transport.  The ExtendedProtectionPolicy.PolicyEnforcement values do not match.  IIS has a value of WhenSupported while the WCF Transport has a value of Never.

Did anyone have an idea how to solve it?

If i'm setting extended protection on IIS to off I can't authenticat at all. (I have browser pop-up but can't login with any user account.)

Thanks,
Naftali.

Comment: Thank you for <extendedProtectionPolicy>-Tags. I din't had any clue where to add it in web.config until i found this Thread!

Comment: I was able to fix this by putting extendedProtectionPolicy in <httpTransport> and <httpsTransport> tags instead of <transport>.

Answer (score 6):

Eventually I got solution for this issue:

the changes was on three different places:

1. IIS **Extended protection** should be turn `off`. **Kernel mode authentication** should be `enabled`.
2. Two changes on the web configuration file:

   1. `<transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"></transport>`
   2. Inside the services configurations `<endpoint address="mex" … />` insetead of `address="rest"`
3. On global.asax  authorization implementation I remove the use of cookies when handling REST requests at:

```cs
public void WindowsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
```

now it's working like a Ninja!

Comment: Thanks.  I had everything sorted, Point 1 above was the missing piece